# Duplicate rotate vertices around obect origin?

Tags: modeling

I have redesigned a repeated part of a larger object, and as a result, had to delete several instances of the "same" vertices. now, I can use `SHIFT`+`D` to make a dupe of the corrected vertex group, but I only get translation control, scale control or rotational control. And in rotational control only Cursor, View, Gimbal, Normal, Local and Global are available, yet the obvious ones of Cursor, Global, and Local only rotate around the same axis of the part:

[image]

However, I need to rotate around the little "orange dot" demarking the item's origin point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 aspects to the definition of the rotation: its Orientation (the *direction* of the axis of rotation), and its Pivot (the *location* of the axis of rotation).

In the illustrated *Adjust Last Operation* panel, you are being offered only the Orientation. If you set the working Pivot to '3D Cursor' in the **header**, and, in Object mode, with your object selected, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*, the pivot should be on the object origin ('the orange dot'), and you should be good to go.

(You can bring up the Pivot options by hitting keyboard  <kbd>.</kbd> (period).)

This assumes one of the Orientation options you are being offered is OK. If it isn't, you may have to create a Custom Orientation for the rotation by checking the little '+' in the *Header > Transform Orientation* dropdown.

And here, there seems to be a bug in my recent 2.91. The panel does **not** offer you your Custom Orientation, along with the others.

It still works.. supposing I set my orientation from a face, then  <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>, the orientation will still be normal to the face, and  <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> will still revert to Global orientation.

Comment: Correction, the Adjust Last panel  does _eventually_ offer the Custom Orientation, but only after a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time, but I found a workaround:

- Move the cursor into the orange pointer.
- swap to cursor mode.
- duplicate the vertices with `Shift`+`D`
- `R`,`Z`, mouseclick click
- in the window "Add Duplicate" *now* choose Cursor
- enter the correct value